# TryParse -- best practices

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tryparse

I have a set of methods which receive user input as strings and parse it to decimals, ints etc at the header of each method. So, I have same code repeated many times in every method, for instance:

```
public ..... CreateOrder(....., string rawSourceAmount)
{
    decimal? sourceAmount2 = rawSourceAmount.
        TryToDecimal(XUtils.DecimalFormat(2)); // extension method, wrapper of Decimal.TryParse, returns null if fails
    if (sourceAmount2 == null)
        throw new XBadSourceAmountException(
            sourceSystem.Id, rawSourceAmount);
    decimal sourceAmount = sourceAmount2.Value;

    ..........
}
```

Why I have `sourceAmount2` and `sourceAmount`? Because later in the method body I actively use sourceAmount, and I do not want each time to write `sourceAmount.Value`. Is there any way to simplify this templated code?

So, the task is: I have `string rawSourceAmount`. I need `decimal sourceAmount` and a place to throw different exception. I do not need `sourceAmount2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw this away and read the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx.

You're doing way too much fuss for simple value parsing.

Comment: Well, ok. You gave me the idea described by @Selman22. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Then change your return type of `TryToDecimal` method.Make it `bool` and add a out parameter to your method,then you can check returning result directly,you don't need to define extra nullable variable:

```
decimal sourceAmount;
if(!rawSourceAmount.TryToDecimal(XUtils.DecimalFormat(2),out sourceAmont)
{
   throw new XBadSourceAmountException(
        sourceSystem.Id, rawSourceAmount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Already have done same code after @pid message.